# how to remove the white focus color in the login and password form?

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4, html5-canvas

whenever i tried to login and enter the credentials on the login form , it creates a white box , it looks weird. Is there any way to remove that?

[image]

im using a three class in the login form .login-form, .form-control, .input-data

.html

```
<input type="email" placeholder="email" aria-describedby="button-addon1" class="form-control login-form input-data">
```

[image]

.css

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm taking about the the white box in the credentials not the outline, i have set the outline to white

Comment: ?? okay, so what is the question if you did set this outline ? Add enough code here to reproduce your issue, it will avoid confusion. it's clear to you, for us we only get a .login-form class style that can be set on any elements aside that input.

Comment: Wait do you mean the background color of the input box? So like if you added `background-color: blue;` or whatever color your background is to the `.login-form` in css, does that fix your issue?  If not, you're going to have to explain more and provide some more code.

Comment: bacground-color ; blue is not working, i have add the code , u can see

Comment: if you really  need help, **read again** : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . your code screen do not even show that you setted a white outline ??

Comment: i solved the error by the help of this https://blog.csdn.net/qq_41253612/article/details/86299602 thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can set the outline when input is focused to none

```css
input:focus{
outline: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try autocomplete="off" in form